# How do I get two different answers?

Tags: vector-analysis, parametrization

"A particle moves along the top of a parabola $y^2=2x$ from left to right at a constant speed of 5 units per seconds. What is the velocity of the particle at the point (2,2)?"

Method one: Let $t=y$. Then, $x=t^2/2$. So, $\vec{r}(t) = (t^2/2,t)$. Taking the derivative will give us the velocity, and since The point (2,2) corresponds to $t=2$, the velocity vector will be (2,1).

Method two: If the particle is moving at a constant speed in the $x$ direction, $dx/dt=5$. Then, $dy/dt = 5/y$ and at the point (2,2), $dy/dt = 5/2$. So, the velocity vector is (5,5/2).

What am I doing wrong in the first method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "method one" the parameter $t$ is not the time! it's just a renaming of $y$ and in the "method two" you cannot use $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=5\,\text{ms}^{-1}$ because we kwnow that the speed is constant not the speed in the x direction! So both methods give wrong answers.

The trajectory is $\pmb r(t)=\left(x(t), y(t)\right)$ and the velocity is $\dot{\pmb r}(t)=\pmb v(t)=\left(\dot x(t), \dot y(t)\right)$ with speed $$v(t)=\sqrt{\dot x^2(t)+ \dot y^2(t)}$$

Recall that if $y=f(x)$ the curve can be parametrized by $x=\lambda t$ and $y=f(\lambda t)$. So for $y^2=2x$ we have 
$$
\pmb r(t)=\left(\lambda t,\sqrt{2\lambda t}\right)\quad\text{and}\quad\pmb v(t)=\left(\lambda,\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\lambda t}}\right)
$$
The point $\pmb r(t^*)=(2,2)$ is on the curve, so we have $\lambda t^*=2 $ and from
$$
v(t)=\sqrt{\lambda^2+ \frac{\lambda^2}{{2\lambda t}}}=5
$$
for all $t$ and in particular for $t^*$ we find 
$$
v(t^*)=\sqrt{\lambda^2+ \frac{\lambda^2}{{2\lambda t^*}}}=\lambda\sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{{4}}}=\lambda \frac{\sqrt 5}{2}=5\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\lambda=2 \frac{5}{\sqrt 5}=2\sqrt{5}
$$
Thus $t^*=\frac{2}{2\sqrt 5}=\frac{\sqrt 5}{5}$ and

> $$
> \pmb v\left(\frac{\sqrt 5}{5}\right)=\left(\lambda,\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\lambda t^*}}\right)=\left(2\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5}\right)
> $$

Another method is the following.
The velocity of the particle along parabola is in the direction of its tangent and can be represented as
$$
\pmb v(\theta)=\left(v\cos\theta,\,v\sin\theta\right)
$$
where $v(\theta)=||\pmb v(\theta)||=5\,\text{ms}^{-1}$ and $\theta=\theta(t)$ is the angle between $\pmb v$ and the $x$ axis varying with the time $t$.
From 
$$
\tan\theta=\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=\frac{1}{y}
$$
At the angle $\theta^*$ corresponnding to the point $(2,2)$ we have
$$
\tan\theta^*=\frac{1}{2}\quad\Longrightarrow \sec\theta^*=\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta^*}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}
$$
so we have
$$
\cos\theta^*=\frac{1}{\sec\theta^*}=\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\quad\text{and}\quad \sin\theta^*=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta^*}=\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{5}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}
$$
Finally the velocity at $\theta^*$ corresponding to the point $(2,2)$ is
$$
\pmb v(\theta^*)=\left(v\cos\theta^*,\,v\sin\theta^*\right)=\left(5\frac{2}{\sqrt 5},\,5\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\right)=\left(2\sqrt{5},\sqrt{5}\right)
$$

A third way may be the following.
If a planar curve in $\Bbb R^2$ is defined by the equation $y=f(x)$, where $f$  is continuously differentiable, then the arc length is given by:
$$
 s=\int _{a}^{b}{\sqrt {1+\left({\frac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}\right)^{2}}}\mathrm dx
$$
So for $y^2=2x$, $y=\sqrt{2x}$, for $x,\,y\ge 0$ and the arc length is given by
$$
 s(t)=\int _{0}^{x(t)}{\sqrt {1+\left({\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}\right)^{2}}}\mathrm dx=\int _{0}^{x(t)}\sqrt {1+\frac{1}{2x}}\;\mathrm dx
$$
and
$$
v(t)=\dot s(t)=\sqrt {1+\frac{1}{2x}}\dot x(t)
$$
This can be also derived immediately from
$$v(t)=\sqrt {\dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t)}=\sqrt{\dot x^2(t)+\frac{\dot x^2(t)}{2x(t)}}=\sqrt {1+\frac{1}{2x(t)}}\dot x(t)$$
We have $v(t)=5\,\text{ms}^{-1}$ and in particular for $t^*$ such that $(x(t^*),y(t^*))=(2,2)$ we have
$$\sqrt {1+\frac{1}{2x(t^*)}}\dot x(t^*)=\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}\dot x(t^*)=5$$
that is $$\dot x(t^*)=5\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}=2\sqrt{5}$$
From $v(t)=\sqrt {\dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t)}$ we find
$$
\dot y(t^*)=\sqrt { v^2(t^*)-\dot x^2(t^*)}=\sqrt { 5^2-(2\sqrt{5})^2}=\sqrt 5
$$
so we have
$$
\pmb v(t^*)=\left(\dot x(t^*),\dot y(t^*)\right)=\left(2\sqrt{5},\sqrt 5\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your method one is that "taking the derivative" is not taking each coordinate separately but is taking the derivative on $s = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = {\sqrt {{t^4\over 4} + t^2}}$. Have you noticed that you did not even use the fact $v=5$ in this method?

EDIT: the real problem with this first method is that you cannot let $t=y$ by assuming the displacement in $y$ direction changes at constant speed.

Your second method is wrong too. $v = {ds\over dt} = 5$ but not ${dx\over dt} = 5$. In fact since $s = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, this means

$$v = {ds\over dt} = {x\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\cdot {dx\over dt} + {y\over{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\cdot {dy\over dt} = {\sqrt 2 \over 2}\cdot ({dx\over dt} + {dy\over dt})$$ at $(2,2)$

And ${dx\over dy} = y = 2$ means $dx = 2dy$ at the point so

$$5 =v =  {\sqrt 2 \over 2}\cdot ({dx\over dt} + {1\over 2}\cdot{dx\over dt})$$

which implies ${dx\over dt} = {10\sqrt2 \over 3}$ and therefore $dy\over dt$ = $5\sqrt 2\over 3$ at the point.

Comment: Is it not plausible to just parameterize the curve though? Is there no way to just do this all in terms of $t$?

Comment: Yes you can do it all in terms of $t$ by taking derivative of ${\sqrt {{t^4\over 4} + t^2}}$ and let it be $5$.

Comment: But what do I do once I find a value for $t$? It's quite messy to be honest

Comment: I am sorry, actually you cannot use $t$ in this way, by letting $t=y$ so are essentailly saying the object moves at a constant speed in $y$ direction which is false. You can let $c = y$ and $x={c^2\over 2}$ for self-defined variable $c$ which is NOT the time, but you would need to find ${dc \over dt}$ which can be non-trivial.

Comment: Ok, one last question. If the speed is 5, shouldn't the magnitude of the velocity vector be equal to 5? Because when I find the length of the vector with the $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ components I do not get 5.

Comment: It depends on what frame of reference you are looking at. My solution assumes we look at the object at point $(0, 0)$. If you use the object itself as the reference point (i.e. you travels with the object), however, you will use $({dx\over dt})^2 + ({dy\over dt})^2 = 5^2$, which is perfectly fine too and would be a much easier problem.

Comment: So how would I solve it in the other reference frame? If I check the magnitude of the velocity vector right now it ends up coming out to $5\sqrt{13}/3$

Comment: In the reference frame where you travels with the particle, you would use $dy = 2dx$ and $({dx\over dt})^2 + ({dy\over dt})^2 = 5^2$ where you will end up with the same answer as in your method one. However it is a coincidence that it ends up with the same answer. If you try on any other point you would not get the same answer since your first method did not even use the velocity $5$.

Comment: But $2^2 + 1^2 \neq 5^2$?

Comment: Oh my bad, in that case it would be $2 \sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{5}$ so it does not coincide with the first method.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be $dy = {dx \over 2}$?

Comment: Yes. I made a typo in the comment above.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @cr001 the arc lenght $s$ is not $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$...and $v=\dot s=\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2}$. So you anwer is wrong.